# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; (fresh homebrew installation)

Tags: mysql, database, homebrew

i installed a fresh mysql via homebrew on my mac (macOS High Sierra V 10.13.6)

i used the command:
$ brew install mysql

After the installation i login in to mysql via terminal
$ mysql -uroot

Create a new table
mysql> create database db_wis;

Want to open in Sequel Pro, but the Programm not start because of a mysql error.

I go back to the terminal and want to view there the tables.
mysql> show database db_wis;

But i get this error:
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database ds_wis' at line 1

I only install, any one an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the Manual:

you can use:

```
-- Create a Database

CREATE DATABASE myDatabase;

-- use Database;

USE myDatabase;

-- Create a Table

CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Col` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


-- Helpfull CMDS

SHOW DATABASES;
SELECT * from myTable;

or

SELECT * FROM myDatabase.myTable;
```